# How do I calculate the loss when samples per batch have different shapes?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I have a training function like so:

```py
def training():
    model.train()
    
    train_mae = []
    
    progress = tqdm(train_dataloader, desc='Training')
    for batch_index, batch in enumerate(progress):
        x = batch['x'].to(device)
        x_lengths = batch['x_lengths'].to(device)
        y = batch['y'].to(device)
        y_type = batch['y_type'].to(device)
        y_valid_indices = batch['y_valid_indices'].to(device)

        # Zero Gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Forward pass
        y_first, y_second = model(x)

        losses = []

        for j in range(len(x_lengths)):
            x_length = x_lengths[j].item()

            if y_type[j].item() == 0:
                predicted = y_first[j]
            else:
                predicted = y_second[j]

            actual = y[j]
            
            valid_mask = torch.zeros_like(predicted, dtype=torch.bool)
            valid_mask[:x_length] = 1
            
            # Padding of -1 is removed from y
            indices_mask = y[j].ne(-1)
            valid_indices = y[j][indices_mask]

            valid_predicted = predicted[valid_mask]
            valid_actual = actual[valid_mask]
            
            loss = mae_fn(valid_predicted, valid_actual, valid_indices)
            
            losses.append(loss)

        # Backward pass and update
        loss = torch.stack(losses).mean()   # This fails due to different shapes
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        
        train_mae.append(loss.detach().cpu().numpy())

        progress.set_description(
            f"mae: {loss.detach().cpu().numpy():.4f}"
        )

    # Return the average MAEs for y type
    return (
        np.mean(train_mae)
    )
```

```py
def mae_fn(output, target, indices):
    clipped_target = torch.clip(target, min=0, max=1)
    maes = F.l1_loss(output, clipped_target, reduction='none')
    return maes[indices]
```

Obviously can't stack these losses since they have different shape due to the indices. Taking mean on `maes[indices]` will solve the issue, but it's resulting in very bad test loss. What do I to calculate the loss here since indices determine the shape depending on y_type.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get an average for each batch, and then combine those averages based on the size of each batch? Larger batches will contribute more to the final mean compared to smaller batches. This should be more stable than equally averaging over all batches. Example below.

```
import torch

#Test data
losses_perbatch = [torch.randn(8, 1), torch.randn(4, 1), torch.randn(2, 1)]

#Weighted mean
total_samples = sum([len(batch) for batch in losses_perbatch])
weighted_mean_perbatch = torch.tensor([batch.sum()
                                       for batch in losses_perbatch]) / total_samples
#Equivalent to:
# weighted_mean_perbatch = torch.tensor([batch.mean() * len(batch)
#                                        for batch in losses_perbatch]) / total_samples

final_weighted_loss = sum(weighted_mean_perbatch)
```

Comment: This didn't work. Test loss got worse somehow.